# What is the usage of "socket" in socket.io connection function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am learning how to use `socket.io` in `nodejs` server. I see a example listed below and I would like to know what's the `socket` in connection function for? Is it a new socket object? And where's the 'id' from? I have googled it but still not understand its function. Thanks

Code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) { //the socket in "function(socket)"
    socket.on('session_id', function (session_id) { socket.session_id = session_id; })
    setInterval(function() {
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's rework your example a little bit to remove a nested function.

```
function connectionHandler (socket) { 
    socket.on('session_id', function (session_id) { 
        socket.session_id = session_id; 
    })
    setInterval(function() {
        socket.emit('date', {'date': new Date()});
    }, 1000);
 }

 io.sockets.on('connection', connectionHandler)
```

In your example, `io.sockets` is your socket.io server. `io.sockets.on('connection', connectionHandler)` registers a connection event handler function.

Then, anytime a client (probably code running in a user's browser) connects, your `connectionHandler` gets called with the `socket` object for the current connection.

`socket.on('session_id')` sets up an event handler to listen for messages sent from clients with `emit('session_id','some message payload')`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer definitely makes it clear. Sorry to make you confuse, the original one should be socket.on('session_id', function ('session_id') { socket.session_id = session_id; }. I typed it wrong. So, "Socket" itself has its own id already?